# Integrating a Bootstrap theme (with custom CSS and JS plugins) with Rails 6 with Webpacker and Yarn/NPM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, yarnpkg, ruby-on-rails-6, webpacker

I have a theme with the following directories structure:

```
+theme
 -index.html
 -file0.html
 ...
 -fileX.html
 +css
  -theme.css
  -theme.min.css
  ...
  -some.css
  -some.min.css
 +js
  -theme.js
  -theme.min.js
 +vendor
  +plugin0
   -plugin0.js
   -plugin0.min.js
  +pluginX
   -pluginX.js
   -pluginX.min.js
 +images
  -image0.jpg
  ...
  -imageX.jpg
  +svg
  -image0.svg
  ...
  -imageX.svg
```

I want to integrate the theme with Rails 6 using Webpacker and package manager like Yarn or NPM.

So far:

- I have installed `Webpacker` and configured it in `environment.js`.
- I have installed all the `js plugins` from the `vendor` folder using `Yarn`.
- I have imported all the installed plugins in my `application.js` file (using `@import 'plugin'`).
- I have imported the plugins not available through `Yarn` by including the respective .js files in `app/javascript/packs/` and using `<script src=""></script>` in my `application.html.erb` file.
- I have imported the `theme.css` in my `applications.scss` file (using `@import 'theme.css`).

And this is where the fun begins: 90% of the theme seems to be working fine but there's some css missing here and some javascript missing there, with no clear error or warning message in the developer tools console.

I understand that you can't help me for this (or any) specific theme but I am hoping that I either have something wrong in my theme integration process or you can suggest a different one that actually works 100%.

I can provide you with the actual `application.js` and `application.html.erb` files as well as the names of the js plugins that don't function properly if required - I just didn't want the question to be huge.

Comment: Good luck! I tried this a while back and got stuck. Ended up writing some of the JS from scratch. The other thing I did was when it used some JS from other libraries, I just imported those into my project, too.

Comment: @sam In which folder did you put those ```js``` files?

Comment: Inside `app/javascript`. For instance, I had a theme that used [Flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/), but I couldn't get the theme's js to work properly. So I added flatpickr through yarn and created a file `app/javascript/date_picker.js`. In it I added `import flatpickr from "flatpickr"` and then a listener for turbolinks to load.

Comment: @sam If you can be a bit more analytical on an answer below I'll try it myself too, let you know if it worked for me and upvote you in any case! Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an easy answer for you, but a couple of pieces to a possible solution. Here are a couple of things I did when I was in a similar boat with a Bootstrap theme.

1. Import bootstrap separately along with the theme's JS. In order to do this I moved the theme's theme.min.js file into `app/javascript` and then imported it as such.

   ```
   # app/javascript/packs/application.js
   require("bootstrap")
   require("theme.min")
   ```
2. Try to add any extra libraries the theme uses manually. So for instance I had a theme that used [Flatpickr](https://flatpickr.js.org/) for selecting dates. I ran `yarn add flatpickr` and then made a js file to use it:

   ```
   # app/javascript/date_picker.js
   import flatpickr from "flatpickr"

   document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
     document.querySelectorAll(".flatpickr").forEach((element) => {
       flatpickr(element, {
         altInput: true,
         altFormat: "F j, Y",
       })
     })
   })

   # app/javascript/packs/application.js
   require("date_picker")
   ```
3. And finally, if that doesn't work, write the JS by hand.

Honestly each of the three solutions worked for parts of the theme's JS. You may also have to add the CSS a little more manually. I did this by adding a `css` folder in my javascript directory, putting the theme's source CSS in that folder and then importing it.

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js
import "css/site"

# app/javascript/css/site.scss
@import "theme.min.css";
@import "feather.css";
@import "flatpickr.min.css";
@import "quill.core.css";
@import "vs2015.css";
```

A lot of those themes have a way to build from the source files into a `dist` folder (or something similar). I think the one I used used `gulp` to build.